# Querying multiple tables in Big Query with different dateformat

Tags: google-bigquery, date-format

I'm very new to working with BigQuery and writing querys

I want to pull data from 2 different tables that each has a field with datestamps but in different formats. All fields are imported as plain text so I have to cast every field to other formats.

Table 1 is formatted '2020-10-09 00:00:00', Table 2 is formatted '2020-10-09' in the date-field
This is the code I use

```
SELECT 
e.Region,
e.OmradeNamn,
SAFE_CAST(e.Datum as Date) as Datum,
FORMAT_DATE('%u', SAFE_CAST(e.Datum as Date)) AS Veckodag,
e.Rutt_Stilling,
...
...
...
...
r.NA_ArbPass,

FROM `leveranskvalitet` e 
  LEFT JOIN `rutterap` r 
  ON e.Rutt_Stilling = r.Rutt_Stilling
  and e.Datum = r.Datum

  Where cast(LEFT(e.Datum,10) as date) =  Cast(@DATUM as date)
  ...
  ...
  Order by e.Rutt_Stilling ASC>
```

From table 2 it only gets 'NULL'

If I use another table as table 1 with the dateformat '2020-10-09' I have no problem pulling data from table 2

To select date I use a cell-reference (@Datum) from another sheet

Grateful for some help with this
Roger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming the data types are timestamp and date you can do the following:

```
with temp_ts as (
 select timestamp('2020-10-09 00:00:00') as ts
),
temp_dt as (
 select date('2020-10-09') as dt
)

select *
from temp_ts t
join temp_dt d
 on extract(date from t.ts) = d.dt;
```

Given your query:

```
SELECT 
e.Region,
e.OmradeNamn,
SAFE_CAST(e.Datum as Date) as Datum,
FORMAT_DATE('%u', SAFE_CAST(e.Datum as Date)) AS Veckodag,
e.Rutt_Stilling,
...
...
...
...
r.NA_ArbPass,

FROM `leveranskvalitet` e 
  LEFT JOIN `rutterap` r 
  ON e.Rutt_Stilling = r.Rutt_Stilling
  and date(cast(e.Datum as datetime) = cast(r.Datum as date)

  Where cast(LEFT(e.Datum,10) as date) =  Cast(@DATUM as date)
  ...
  ...
  Order by e.Rutt_Stilling ASC>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. BUT, I´m a newbie to this. How do I use this?
I put your code first, but what do I have to change in my code

Comment: in your scenario above which is table 1 and which is table 2?

Comment: `leveranskvalitet` e  is table 1 and  `rutterap` r  is table 2

Comment: I've updated my answer, the join to `rutterap` now includes the extract date logic.

Comment: This last part gives an error. Like I wrote in the question, all fields are just plain text, no filed is formatted, so I have to cast every field.
The error is "EXTRACT for argument types: DATE FROM STRING", so I guess that is because it is plain text and not a real date. Any suggestions?